# Navigation with a ternary operator to set active class to the DIRECTORY link

Tags: php-7

All my pages are in DIRECTORIES and are ALL named index.php

I use independent modules, each in its own directory, so that they can be dropped into any web app. The links and the URLs end with: "directory_name/".
basurl(); is a function to simplify links.

```
init.php  
defined('PDQURL') or define('PDQURL', 'http://pdq/dev/');  
function base_url($location) {return PDQURL.$location;}  

nav.php
<a class="nav-link" href="<?=base_url('index.php')?>">Home</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="<?=base_url('conversions/')?>">Conversions</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="<?=base_url('employees/')?>">Employees</a>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to do the Navigation with a ternary operator to set active class to the DIRECTORY link?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the current URL of your page. Actually there are different ways to get the current url with php. I 'm using the following piece of code.

```
$current = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") 
    . "://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
```

After you 've got the current called uri, juxt compare it with your base url.

```
<a class="nav-link<?= base_url('example.php') == $current ? ' active-link' : '' ?>">Example</a>
```

This means, that if you call your example.php page, and the current url matches the result of your `base_url()` function, the `active-link` css class will be displayed.

Comment: What I need is to get the directory, that way the directory contents will make the link active.

Comment: Well ... didn 't get the point. The question / your issue is not clear. Please define properly, what you have so far and where do you want to go and what you 've tried so far.

Comment: The description states: "All my pages are in DIRECTORIES and are ALL named index.php".  
Herein lies the issue, if I make index.php 'active' all of them are. Apologies if it wasn't clear enough

Comment: Have you tried my code example? In the given example above `$current` is the full qualified url, which includes the directory and the index.php. What 's wrong with that? What is your expected result?

Comment: It gives all the index pages the active class.